# Angular: testing checkbox change event issue

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm trying to test a component with a checkbox but I can't find a solution to test checkbox-change event.

Here is my component to be tested:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-useparent-checkbox',
    template: `
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            (change)="changeChecked($event.currentTarget.checked)">`
})
export class UseparentCheckboxComponent {

    @Output() toggle = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    changeChecked(isChecked: boolean) {
        this.toggle.emit(isChecked);
    }
}
```

and here is the test code:

```
let comp: UseparentCheckboxComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<UseparentCheckboxComponent>;

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [ FormsModule ],
        declarations: [
            UseparentCheckboxComponent
        ],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UseparentCheckboxComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
});

it ('should send true when selected', fakeAsync(() => {

    const inputDe = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
    const inputEl = inputDe.nativeElement;

    expect(inputEl.checked).toBeFalsy();

    let result;
    comp.toggle.subscribe((res: boolean) => {
        console.log('result', res);
        result = res;
    });

    inputDe.triggerEventHandler('change', new Event('change'));

    tick();
    expect(result).toBe(true);
}));
```

And I have this error: "Cannot read property 'checked' of null".
It looks like the problem is in "$event.currentTarget.checked": My new Event('change') has no target or currentTarget value.

If I change the event to click I got the same issue.
I could change my component code to get the checkbox value not from the event but with a viewChild or somthing like that but I think the current code is better.

Does anyone have a solution?
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check bellow code this will helps..

```
it ('should send true when selected', fakeAsync(() => {

const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
const elem = compiled.querySelector('#revert-project');

expect(elem.checked).toBeFalsy();
elem.change(); //or you can use click();
expect(elem.checked).toBe(true);
}));
```

Comment: This does not update the model (component). It still has old values.