# Jasmine test case for checkbox event handler Angular 16, jasmine 4.3.5

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular16

I have to test below function

```
  addAll($event: any) {
    this.Deletion = [];
    if ($event['srcElement']['checked']) {
      this.Model.forEach(file => {
        this.Deletion.push(file.docId);
      });
    }
  }
```

This function add files in Deletion array if checkbox is checked

HTML is as below

```
<input type="checkbox" id="addAllCheckBox" (change)="addAll($event)">
```

Spec.ts file

```
  it('should call addAll on checkbox change event', fakeAsync(() => {
    const handleSpy = spyOn(component, 'addAll');

    const myCheckBox = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#addAllCheckBox'));
    tick();

    fixture.whenStable().then(res => {
      fixture.detectChanges();

      myCheckBox.triggerEventHandler('change', { target: { checked: true } });
      expect(handleSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  }));
```

I am getting an ERROR

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of
> null (reading 'triggerEventHandler')

I created this testcase by taking below refereces from stackoverflow

[Jasmine test for checkbox change handler function in angular 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68410322/jasmine-test-for-checkbox-change-handler-function-in-angular-12)

[Angular: testing checkbox change event issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53739616/angular-testing-checkbox-change-event-issue)

I search on the internet for this issue but I did not understand why I m getting this error

How should I solve this issue?

Comment: This isn't enough to help you.  It's clear your element is not defined but you provided no context to how it is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show the full template but here are some recommendations anyway:

1. Check if your checkbox input is inside some *ngIf and it receives true at the time you're trying to access your checkbox via te query selector.
2. Remove fakeAsync and replace it with this:

```
it('should call addAll on checkbox change event', (done) => { ... });
```

3. call `detectChanges` before accessing the checkbox via the query selector (after zone is stabilized):

```
fixture.detectChanges();

fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    const myCheckBox = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#addAllCheckBox'));

    myCheckBox.triggerEventHandler('change', { target: { checked: true } });

    expect(handleSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

    done();
});
```

Please, let me know if you succeeded in accessing the checkbox reference.

Comment: Hi @AramKhachatrian, I succeeded in accessing checkbox reference. My checkbox was inside nested if blocks that was the issue. your answer's first point solve my issue also  I have modified the test function as per your recommendation. Thank you so much Aram Khachatrian .... :-)